# Add permission to multiple group to a folder

Tags: permissions, users, groups

Suppose I have this situation (user : groups):

```
userA : groupA all mix1
userB : groupB all mix1
userC : groupC all mix2
userD : groupD all
```

Suppose I have read access to "folderX" to user "userA" and group "mix1"

There is a way to grant read permission to members of groups mix1 and mix2?

Creating a group "groupX" and adding all users to that group, then change the owner-group of the folder would be a solution but it's too hard to keep update if my users changes.